bash: ./ipsweep.sh: cannot execute: required file not found
Im trying to run an ipsweep script i wrote following a video and i found a common problem being bash: ./ipsweep.sh: cannot execute: required file not found , i have given permissions to read, write and execute using chmod u+x ipsweep.sh any insight would be helpful.
here is the script -
#!bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "" ] 
then 
echo "You for got to put in an IP!"
echo "Syntax: ./ipsweep.sh 192.168.4" 

else
for ip in `seq 1 254`; do
ping -c 1 $1.$ip | grep "64 bytes" | cut -d " " -f 4 | tr -d ":" &
done
fi


are you running ./ipsweep.sh really from the same directory that ipsweep.sh is in?

when running the ls command in (USER㉿USER)-[~] i see ipsweep.sh as and saved file and when i run ./ipsweep.sh under the same directory im presented with file not found               specifically this is what shows-       description-pak  Desktop  Documents  Downloads  ipsweep.sh  msfinstall  Music  Pictures  Public  Templates  Videos

it's highly likely that you don't have a shell interpreter available as bin/bash where you're running the script. You probably mean to have /bin/bash there instead. (You're also not showing which video you're looking at, so we can't tell how reasonable a source it is.)

Wow tysm it was the little / i missed out and this is the video btw https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNzpcB7ODxQ&t=8834s&pp=ygUnZXRoaWNhbCBoYWNraW5nIGZ1bGwgY291cnNlIGluIDEyIGhvdXJz     i am aware it is 2 years old if you have  a more full proof suggestion i would be happy to check it out however so far this has taught me alot

@Rocket_Seeds, yep, good. And yeah, if it was right in the video, then ok, do go on. If it had been wrong there, I'd have suggested taking the rest of the video with a grain of salt, too. (I didn't check that particular video at all, but I wouldn't be surprised to find some really bad resources online. Better get away from such as quickly as possible.)
